# Interactive Video using Python

Tags: python, video, tkinter

I was just wondering if making an interactive video in Python 3.6 would be possible? I looked at options for actually inputting videos into Tkinter using python-gstreamer but I couldn't get it to work.

So could anyone suggest a way and explain how to get a video to play in Python? So perhaps there could be a Tkinter window and this video could be displayed in this frame?

If Python isn't possible any other ideas are welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with the Video widget in a jupyter notebook:

```py
from ipywidgets import Video, Image
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import Checkbox
fileA= 'videoA.mp4'
fileB= 'videoB.mp4'
video = Video.from_file(fileB)
top_toggle = Checkbox(description='Change Video')

def video_loader(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        video.value = f.read()
def video_change(button):
    if button['new']:
        video_loader(fileA)
    else:
        video_loader(fileB)
top_toggle.observe(video_change, names='value')

display(top_toggle)
display(video)
```

See also here:
https://github.com/QuantStack/quantstack-talks/blob/master/2018-11-14-PyParis-widgets/notebooks/1.ipywidgets.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

The following code makes a Tkinter window and displays a video in it. You will need to install some dependencies if you don't already have the required libraries.

```
import tkinter as tk, threading
import imageio
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

name = "video.mp4" # video file path
video = imageio.get_reader(name)

def stream(label):

    for data in video.iter_data():
        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(data))
        label.config(image=frame_image)
        label.image = frame_image

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    video_label = tk.Label(root)
    video_label.pack()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(video_label,))
    thread.daemon = 1
    thread.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just one question, my video playback is rather slow. It seems to be something with the frame rate. Any idea how that can be fixed? Thanks!